# Issue when installing firebase-server

Tags: node.js, npm, firebase

I'm trying to install firebase-server on my pc, but I'm still getting an error when trying.

I type `npm install firebase-server` on my console but It failed each time.

This is the npm log http://pastebin.com/d6Vewvaa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting no access.

Try running as super user.

```
sudo npm install firebase-server
```

Comment: As I could see in your logs you have successfully installed `firebase-server`.  Your problem now is with `node-gyp rebuild`

Comment: But if I type firebase-server in my console, it does not work, :/. And node-gyp rebuild, got issue.

Comment: take a look at firebase-server documentation. https://github.com/urish/firebase-server. As i can see here you will run it through `node_modules/.bin/firebase-server -p 5555` so make sure you are in the dir where you have your node_modules folder.

Comment: yw. you will need the firebase as well. `sudo npm install firebase` might help. or add firebase to you package.json